# watchOS 1 storyboard crashes in Xcode 7

Tags: watchkit, xcode-storyboard, swift2, xcode7, watchos-2

I am converting my project over to Xcode 7 and Swift 2.  I also had a WatchKit Extension, and I allowed Xcode to convert that to watchOS 2.

When I go to open the storyboard, I get this crash. Are some storyboards broken and so they need manual adjustments?

> Process:               Xcode [97053]
>
> Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
>
> Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
>
> Version:               7.0 (8163.8)
>
> Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-8163008000000000~7
>
> Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
>
> Parent Process:        ??? [1]
>
> Responsible:           Xcode [97053]
>
> User ID:               504
>
> Date/Time:             2015-07-16 18:39:19.620 -0400
>
> OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
>
> Report Version:        11
>
> Anonymous UUID:        56576435-6521-AF4C-A27C-F5E11A057A25
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       BAA76D42-23AC-45B6-A291-6CFFB2574157
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 1300000 seconds
>
> Time Since Wake:       10000 seconds
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>
> Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information:
>
> ProductBuildVersion: 7A152u
>
> ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-8124.4/InterfaceBuilder/RemoteToolCommunication/IBObjectMarshalling.m:694
>    Details:  Failed to launch remote tool: Failed to find or create
>   execution context for description
>    System content
>   2x for IBIPadFramework w/ default fidelity: Failed to find a suitable
>   device for the type SimDeviceType :
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air with runtime SimRuntime
>   : 9.0 (13A4293g) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0 (Failure
>   reason: Failed to create new simulator device that matches
>   SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air for
>   runtime SimRuntime : 9.0 (13A4293g) -
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0 ((null)))
>
> Object:
>
> Method:
>   +valueForKeyPath:ofClassNamed:usingMarshaller:targetRuntime:context:explicitScaleFactor:diagnosticsBlock:
>
> Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
>
> Hints:   None
>
> Backtrace:
>
> 0  0x000000010b5630f7 -[IDEAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in IDEKit)
>
> 1  0x000000010a16e7f2 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
>
> 2  0x000000010a16ea09 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in
>   DVTFoundation)
>
> 3  0x000000011a88a32f (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
>
> 4  0x000000011a889eda (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
>
> 5  0x000000011a86d3cf (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
>
> 6  0x000000011a86daf1 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
>
> 7  0x000000010a1a9464 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in
>   DVTFoundation)
>
> 8  0x00007fff98b87323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in
>   libdispatch.dylib)
>
> 9  0x00007fff98b82c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in
>   libdispatch.dylib)
>
> 10  0x00007fff98b8ecbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in
>   libdispatch.dylib)
>
> 11  0x00007fff92ea33f9
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** (in CoreFoundation)
>    12  0x00007fff92e5e68f __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
>
> 13  0x00007fff92e5dbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
>
> 14  0x00007fff8d77456f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
>
> 15  0x00007fff8d7742ea ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
>
> 16  0x00007fff8d77412b
>   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
>    17  0x00007fff8cbab8ab _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
>
> 18  0x00007fff8cbaae58 -[NSApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
>
> 19  0x000000010a72b5fe -[DVTApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
>
> 20  0x00007fff8cba0af3 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
>
> 21  0x00007fff8cb1d244 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
>
> 22  0x00007fff8b7255c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes", then remove the runtime - the runtime is old. After, reboot Xcode7, and launch the Simulator...

See more at, [Xcode 7 Beta 4 no simulators and can't open nibs](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11706?sr=stream&ru=8243).